# Javascript Discord Bot API Request

Tags: javascript, api, get, request

I'm trying to make a api request to a api that shows game data. I'm only used to using Axios so I don't really know how to make these kind of requests but I would like to learn. Here is the request I should make, all I would like to ask is how can I get the responce? Like I said processing the data and that stuff won't be to hard only the request is hard for me thnx!

```
GET https://public-api.tracker.gg/v2/csgo/standard/profile/steam/76561198008049283
TRN-Api-Key: API_KEY
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
```

Comment: You say you're used to Axios so what have you tried? Is it not working? If so, what errors are reported?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain it the right way. I'm used to do it with a link request so the formating is nothing like this. https://gyazo.com/c0bf4b8a2f4d4dc04aeeac3fecb1216e

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I found out that I was not thinking and I can use headers with axios. Still thanks for the help